# Large insert an user table causing lock with tempdb

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using sql server 2008 , i have a huge table that basically insert in to a large amount of data in 10 minute interval. The table contains thirty five columns, and a single load of data can contain two million records.At the time of insertion the tempdb database being locked.
So other queries goes to lock mode which are using temporary tables.

How can you fix these lock on tempdb database?

Thank you for your help.
Ralaad

Comment: What is the actual lock resource that these queries are blocked on? You can get this from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks

Comment: wait_type resource_address
LAZYWRITER_SLEEP NULL
BROKER_TO_FLUSH NULL
SQLTRACE_INCREMENTAL_FLUSH_SLEEP NULL
REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH 0x0000000029DD01F8
LOGMGR_QUEUE 0x00000000038480D0
XE_TIMER_EVENT NULL
FT_IFTS_SCHEDULER_IDLE_WAIT NULL
XE_DISPATCHER_WAIT NULL
CHECKPOINT_QUEUE 0x0000000003861450
LAZYWRITER_SLEEP NULL
DISPATCHER_QUEUE_SEMAPHORE NULL
KSOURCE_WAKEUP NULL
BROKER_EVENTHANDLER NULL
BROKER_TRANSMITTER NULL
BROKER_TRANSMITTER NULL
ONDEMAND_TASK_QUEUE 0x0000000003826888

Comment: the waiting task given above. Please advice

Comment: Filter on just session ids greater than 50. Those all look like standard system waits. How did you diagnose that these queries were waiting on a lock?

Comment: Could not find any record having session id greater than 50.

Comment: Inserting the huge table with thousand records, at that time all the other queries seems to be locked.I am working 16 core processor windows server 2012.

Comment: You need to run this when you are encountering the issue described in the question. Do you have any queries you think are blocked at the moment?

Comment: This much cores automatically enable the lock partitioning on Sql server. is this will cause locks?

Comment: So far you haven't shown any evidence of queries waiting on locks at all. How did you come to this diagnosis?

Comment: Now i got the wainting tasks, it given below
task_address-wait_type - resourceaddress - resource_desc
0x000000000484EE08 - PAGEIOLATCH_EX - 0x0000001370FB85C0 - 7:223:4396665
0x000000001670CBC8-PAGEIOLATCH_EX-0x0000001004FDDE80-7:1:4507151

Comment: Those aren't locks. They are waiting on pages from database id 7 to be read from disc.

Comment: Btw how many files does that database actually have? Looks like at least 223.